# Error 500 when posting json to alfresco sites api

Tags: python, alfresco

I'm trying to POST to the sites api to create a site (obviously :-))
I'm posting the following:

```
payload={'description':'My description', 'visibility':'PUBLIC', 
'site-preset':'site-dashboard','title':'My Site name', "shortName":'my-site-name'}
```

as:

```
requests.post('http://<myserver>:8080/alfresco/service/api/sites',
auth=('admin','XXXXX'), data=json.dumps(payload))
```

in python. I get back a 500 error detailed below. What else do I need to add to the request to get this to work? I can't find the docs which define the headers further than http://docs.alfresco.com/3.4/references/RESTful-SiteSitesPost.html and I've been using this example:https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/create-site-alfresco-using-open-cmis-extension-07312013 however defining much more than is there.

The below clearly states that site.shortName is not defined, therefore how should I define shortName in the json I pass to the sites api so that the alfresco sites api pick it up? References to docs are also very very welcome.

Error log below:

```
{u'callstack': [u'',
u'freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression site.shortName is undefined on line 9, column 56 in org/alfresco/repository/site/site.lib.ftl.',
u'freemarker.core.TemplateObject.assertNonNull(TemplateObject.java:125)',
u'freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:118)',
u'freemarker.core.AddConcatExpression._getAsTemplateModel(AddConcatExpression.java:98)',
u'freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)',
u'freemarker.core.ListLiteral.getModelList(ListLiteral.java:119)',
u'freemarker.core.MethodCall._getAsTemplateModel(MethodCall.java:91)',
u'freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)',
u'freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:93)',
u'freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:76)',
u'freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)',
u'freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)',
u'freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)',
u'freemarker.core.EscapeBlock.accept(EscapeBlock.java:84)',
u'freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)',
u'freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)',
u'freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)',
u'freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:172)',
u'freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:614)',
u'freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:106)',
u'freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)',
u'freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:172)',
u'freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:614)',
u'freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:106)',
u'freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)',
u'freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)',
u'freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)',
u'freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:199)',
u'org.alfresco.repo.template.FreeMarkerProcessor.process(FreeMarkerProcessor.java:218)',
u'org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.renderTemplate(AbstractWebScript.java:896)',
u'org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.renderFormatTemplate(DeclarativeWebScript.java:267)',
u'org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:147)',
u'org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:429)',
u'org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:452)',
u'org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:491)',
u'org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:529)',
u'org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:341)',
u'org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:378)',
u'org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)',
u'org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)',
u'javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)',
u'org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)',
u'org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)',
u'org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)',
u'org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)',
u'org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)',
u'org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)',
u'org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)',
u'org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)',
u'org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)',
u'org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)',
u'org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)',
u'org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)',
u'org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)',
u'org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)',
u'org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)',
u'org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)',
u'org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)',
u'org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)',
u'org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)',
u'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)',
u'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)',
u'java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)',
u"org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.TemplateException: 06020108 Error during processing of the template 'Expression site.shortName is undefined on line 9, column 56 in org/alfresco/repository/site/site.lib.ftl.'. Please contact your system administrator.",
u'org.alfresco.repo.template.FreeMarkerProcessor.process(FreeMarkerProcessor.java:222)',
u"org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 06020018 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 06020108 Error during processing of the template 'Expression site.shortName is undefined on line 9, column 56 in org/alfresco/repository/site/site.lib.ftl.'. Please contact your system administrator.",
u'org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:1067)'],
u'exception': u"org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException - 06020018 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 06020108 Error during processing of the template 'Expression site.shortName is undefined on line 9, column 56 in org/alfresco/repository/site/site.lib.ftl.'. Please contact your system administrator.",
u'message': u"06020018 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 06020108 Error during processing of the template 'Expression site.shortName is undefined on line 9, column 56 in org/alfresco/repository/site/site.lib.ftl.'. Please contact your system administrator.",
u'server': u'Community v4.2.0 (r63893-b12) schema 6,033',
u'status': {u'code': 500,
u'description': u'An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request.',
u'name': u'Internal Error'},
u'time': u'02-Jul-2014 15:15:01'}
```

Update:
I've since (partially thanks to Jeff's answer programmatically created a usable site by creating one in the repo and then using enable-site.get.js (google it) to complete the process. Hey presto, a usable site! The key thing is to call siteData.newPreset("site-dashboard", ) in the javascript layer (please someone correct me if I'm seeing a symptom and not the actual solution) to actually generate the required xml in the AVM store so the site is usable. create-site should do this; however I've not yet got that to work yet, hence the two-step process. Many seem to have got create-site to work well.

create-site required OAuth authentication. The error I posted was the result of not passing over properly formatted json; I did repeated tests with curl (as suggested by Jeff Potts) and Postman -- the Chromium app. I am now a happy bunny (although I still don't understand why create-site did nothing but anyway; I have a solution)

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with your request - _"Expression site.shortName is undefined on line 9, column 56 in org/alfresco/repository/site/site.lib.ftl.'. Please contact your system administrator."_ The `shortName` you are passing doesn't correspond to a template value that it can replace when creating your site.

Comment: Good observation but I'd bet that the request isn't getting parsed correctly as others have this precise request working with the same server, which I've not modified. I added in the headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'} too and this simply gave me a bad request instead. I'm unsure of what to add in the headers as none of the documentation I've seen details it. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What specific version of Alfresco are you running?

Comment: 4.2e -- that should have been in the original question; sorry.

Comment: @JeffPotts Do you have any suggestions as to what may be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

First, be aware that calling this method successfully will not result in a functioning site in Alfresco Share. That fact is documented in the site.post web script documentation, which can be found here:

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/script/org/alfresco/repository/site/sites.post
```

If you aren't intending to create a functional Alfresco Share site and you still want to create the site folder structure on the repository tier, which is what this web script does, then the payload you need to supply should look like this:

```
{"title":"Test Site 1","visibility":"PUBLIC","description":"","sitePreset":"site-dashboard","shortName":"test-site-1"}
```

Notice that it is using "sitePreset" and not "site-preset" as you originally had.

When I call this against my local 4.2.f server using the following curl statement I get a successful response:

```
curl -uadmin:admin -X POST "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/sites" -H "content-type: application/json" -d@/var/tmp/site.json
```

There is no supported way to create a Share site programmatically, at least as of 4.2.f.

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks. The URL you've helpfully posted details that to create a fully functioning site "...Currently, creating a site programmatically needs to be done in the Share context, using the create-site module." However, when I post to that I get a 500 error with the template as before. Does this really create a site programmatically as the doc says?

Comment: Here's the error:"message": "06080006 Failed to process template org/alfresco/modules/create-site.post.json.ftl",
    "exception": "org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException - 06080006 Failed to process template org/alfresco/modules/create-site.post.json.ftl",
    "callstack": [
        "",
        "freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression success is undefined on line 2, column 17 in org/alfresco/modules/create-site.post.json.ftl.",

Comment: After some time fixing these errors, I have created a site with this n the repo. Is tehre a doc that details what else I need to do to this to make it usable? I used create-site, which is documented to set up the web-tier level, but it did nothing; just a 200 was returned (I'd expect a 201).